# Install Bot framework with nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botframework, nuget-package

I see in the documentation I must download a Template to use the bot Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart

There is a way to install this tempalte with nuget ? I find the package for nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/
But I must create a project to use the cmd Install-Package

How install the bot framewokr only with nuget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation article, which you are referring to, does not say you have to install any framework. What it recommends is to install the project template. Project templates are not frameworks, they just have some pre-included files.

The same documentation article clearly says that the framework itself is a nuget package. They say:

> By using the Bot Application template, you're creating a project that already contains all of the components that are required to build a simple bot, including a reference to the Bot Builder SDK for .NET, Microsoft.Bot.Builder. Verify that your project references the latest version of the SDK:
>
> 1. Right-click on the project and select Manage NuGet Packages.
> 2. In the Browse tab, type "Microsoft.Bot.Builder".
> 3. Locate the Microsoft.Bot.Builder package in the list of search
>    results, and click the Update button for that package.
> 4. Follow the prompts to accept the changes and update the package.
>
> Thanks to the Bot Application template, your project contains all of the code that's necessary to create the bot in this tutorial. You won't actually need to write any additional code. However, before we move on to testing your bot, take a quick look at some of the code that the Bot Application template provided.

This basically means that there is no requirement to have this project template. What you can do is actually install the template, create a project and look at the project structure and packages. Then, you are free to reproduce the same project structure and add necessary references yourself, without using project template.

Again, the template is just a bootstrap code.

Comment: Hum ok, I understand much what is the tempalte Bot Application and the role playing by nuget, thanks you